# Backbone.js collection where

Tags: backbone.js

I'm triyng to do a filter on a collection, the model is a Student like this:

```
{
   code: "some code",
   name: "some name",
   course: {
      course_code: "some code",
      course_name: "course name"
   }
}
```

if I try to do a filter like this:

```
var myVar = students.where({code: "some code"})
```

myVar will be filled with students according to the code and there are no problems. But how can I do filter by course_code?
I already tried:

```
var myVar = students.where({course: {course_code: "some code"}})
```

but I get nothing, if I try

```
var myVar = students.where({course.course_code: "some code"})
```

I get error.

Answer (score 3):

let's assume you are finding students with course code 101.

```
var student_with_course_code = students.filter(function(student) {
      return student.get('course').get('code') == 101;
});
```

Comment: But there is no way to do it using the where function?

Comment: I think where only works with references, not values, like you'd be using. My understanding might be a little off here. Go filtering instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myVar = students.find(function(s) {return s.course.course_code == "some code"} )
```

Comment: kepp in mind that .find only returns the first student, regarding to the definition: http://underscorejs.org/#find